# Get selected row of number and return it into Integer format

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How should I implement into getRow2() to get the selected row of number? So that I can moveToPosition(x);

MainActivity.java as below:

```
Database db = new Database(this);
int x = db.getRow2();
Cursor cursor = db.getName();
cursor.moveToPosition(x);
tvName.setText(cursor.getString(0));
```

Database.java as below:

```
public int getRow2(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int rows = -1;
    try {
        rows = (int) db.compileStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TBL_USER).simpleQueryForLong();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return -1;
    }
    return rows;
}


public Cursor getName(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name from TBL_USER",null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to move the cursor's index to the last row?

Comment: There is no id in the cursor. You select only the column `name`. Edit your question and explain better what you want.

Comment: I just hope the cursor can move to certain row.

Comment: Which row? Do you want a specific row for which you know the name or by position?

Comment: When user enter 'username', the database get the same username's row such as (Name, Username, Pass).
The cursor will get the entire list of Name and i try to use the moveToPosition for specific position where username exist in certain row. Is it possible? Or any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Use moveToNext() instead of moveToPosition()
What a simple question